# how to validate dropdownlist using the DataAnnotation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I need your help, I have a problem with the validation using AdataAnnotation

I am trying to validate a dropdown list using it but there is some problem with it

this is my code

> View Side

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("addNewProject", "Activities", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


            @Html.ValidationMessage("ProjectName")
            <h3>Project Name: </h3>
            @Html.TextBox("ProjectName", null,  new { @class = "text_field"} )

            @Html.ValidationMessage("ProjectOwner")
            <h3>Project Owner: </h3>
            @Html.DropDownList("ProjectOwner", (SelectList)ViewBag.Customers, new { @class = "text_field" })

            @Html.ValidationMessage("Description")
            <h3>Description: </h3>
            @Html.TextArea("Description", new { @class = "text_area"})

            @Html.ValidationMessage("Department")
            <h3>Departments: </h3>
            @Html.DropDownList("Department", (SelectList)ViewBag.Departments, new { @class = "list" })

            @Html.ValidationMessage("Region")
            <h3>Regions: </h3>
            @Html.DropDownList("Region", (SelectList)ViewBag.Regions, new { @class = "list" })

            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit" />
        }
```

> Controller Side

```
    public ActionResult NewProject()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

        list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "Choose ..." });

        list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "First" });

        list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Second" });

        list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Third" });

        ViewBag.Departments = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.Regions = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");

        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult addNewProject(Project newProject)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("NewProject", newProject);
        }
    }
```

> The Data Holder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace workflow.DataHolders
{
    public class Project : DataHolder
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field Is Required")]
        [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Length Of The Title Should Be More Than 3 Letters")]
        public string ProjectName{ get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field Is Required")]
        public List<SelectListItem> ProjectOwner { get; set; }

        string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field Is Required")]
        public List<SelectListItem> Department { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This Field Is Required")]
        public List<SelectListItem> Region { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: What validation are your expecting - all the options you render have a `value` attribute so it could never be invalid. And all 3 dropdownlists are trying to bind to properties which are `List<SelectListItem>` which cant work - a `<select>` element only binds to a single value type, not a collection of complex objects

Comment: but it always give me invalid value, I do not know why

Comment: Of course - because your tryng to bind to a property which is `List<SelectListItem>` - the properties needs to be `int Region`, `int Department` etc. I will add an answer shortly will more detail of this and other issues in your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 main issues with you code.

First your trying to bind a `<select>` to a property which is `List<SelectListItem>`, but a `<select>` only posts back a single value type which can't be bound to `List<SelectListItem>` so the property is `null` and validation fails. Your properties need to be (for example) typeof `int` or `string`.

Secondly, your manually adding a `SelectListItem` with `Value ="0"` and `Text = "Choose ..."` which means that even if you correct the first issue, if the user selects the first option ("Choose ..."), your model will be valid because "0" is a valid value.

Your class needs to be

```
public class Project : DataHolder
{
  ....

  [Display(Name = "Project Owner")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a project owner")]
  public int ProjectOwner { get; set; }

  public List<SelectListItem> ProjectOwnerList { get; set; }

  .... // ditto for Department and Region
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public ActionResult NewProject()
{
  List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
  list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "First" });
  list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Second" });
  list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Third" });
  // Initialize the model
  Project model = new Project();
  model.ProjectOwnerList = list;
  model.DepartmentList = list;
  model.RegionList = list;
  return View(model); // always return a model even if its just a default new instance!
}
```

Note your model contains properties for `List<SelectListItem>` so don't use `ViewBag`, and in any case, the `DropDownList()` method only requires `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as its second parameter, so creating a new `SelectList` from `List<SelectListItem>` is just unnecessary extra overhead

Then in the view

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectOwner)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProjectOwner, Model.ProjectOwnerList, "Choose...")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectOwner)
```

Note that the 3rd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` adds a `labelOption` with a `null` value - `<option value>Choose...</option>` -, so if its selected, youu will now get an error message and the model will be invalid.

Assuming the user selects `"Second"`, then when you post back, the value of `ProjectOwner` will be `2`.

Comment: I have added a new modified answer to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is a very good answer but still it has one problem, the problem appears when it fails to validate one of the fields it will redirect you to the same page and now you will have a problem because in your code you did not initiate any new list at that case so you will get Error because the values of the lists in the object are nulls.

your code could be modified like this to solve this problem.

> Add this to your code to organize it and you could add more than one GetList method depending on your needs.

```
List<SelectListItem> GetList()
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = "Choose ..." });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "First" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Second" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Third" });

    return list;
}
```

> Modify the addNewProject method to be like this.

```
public ActionResult addNewProject(Project newProject)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {

        newProject.ProjectOwnerList = GetList();
        newProject.DepartmentList = GetList();
        newProject.RegionList = GetList();

        return View("NewProject", newProject);
    }
}
```

*Note that you will not notice this problem if you use the DataAnnotation Client Side Validation, but even if you use the Client Side validation you have to solve that problem*

Comment: Remove the `list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = "Choose ..." });` and do it correctly by using the overload of `DropDownListFor()` that accepts an `optionLabel` - see my answer

Comment: And the common approach is to use a `private void ConfigureViewModel(Project model) { // populate select lists and other common stuff }` so you only need one line of code in the GET and POST methods

Comment: I think even when you use the overloaded DropDownListFor() with out initiating a new list for each list in the object you will get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" because even in the overloaded method you are using the object "Model.ProjectOwnerList".

Comment: Of course you need to initialize the `SelectList`. My comment was that the the correct way to generate the _"Please select.."_ option is to use the overload :)

Comment: That's what I wanted to draw the attention to :)

Comment: Sorry, just assumed you know that

Comment: no worries, it is to make the answer comprehensive, maybe me and you know about this but other might not know.