# Why isn't this dropdown validating client side?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

In this example, I have a car model and I want to specify the 'make' of the car with a dropdown. A 'make' is required.

I have clientside validation enabled in the web.config:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

I have the set the 'make' property as required in the car model:

```
 public class car
    {
        public int carId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int makeId { get; set; }

        virtual public make make { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string carModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class make {

        public int makeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string  makeName { get; set; }

    }
```

JQuery Validation is referenced in the view but the dropdown is only validated when the form is submitted?

```
@model validation.Models.car

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>car</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.makeId, "makeId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("makeId", null, "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.makeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.carModel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.carModel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.carModel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

If I turn off UnobtrusiveJavaScript then  neither 'carmodel' or 'make' validate client-side, both only validate server-side.

```
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
```

Comment: and validation is working on carModel textbox?

Comment: Yes, that validates client-side. But if a car make is not selected then this error is only flagged when the form is posted and then model fails to validate.

Comment: Your problem is that you have placed a `[Required]` attribute on a value type (int).  This is useless, because value types always have a value, and cannot be null.  Thus, the required functionality is always satisfied, because the default value of 0 is a value.  Make your model attributes nullable to solve this problem.  The reason the carMake value is validated is that string types are reference types and are thus nullable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: [how to validate dropdownlist using the DataAnnotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099817/how-to-validate-dropdownlist-using-the-dataannotation)

I used the DropDownListFor helper instead of the DropDownList. Now the drop down validates client side.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.makeId, ViewBag.makes as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I not entirely sure why this would fix the problem, if anyone can shed any light?