# compare if a string is valid in validation form using .net

Tags: c#, .net, validation, annotations, compare

I have a create form with this div

```
<div>
    <label asp-for="Department">Department</label>
    <select asp-for="Department" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<OptionListDepartments>()"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Department" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

so with this div I'll show something like this :

[image]

I wrote my method for create in controller in this way:

```
[HttpPost("home/create")]
    public IActionResult create(Employee e)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _employeeRepository.addEmployee(e);

            return RedirectToAction("/");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("/Views/Home/Create.cshtml");
        }
        
    }
```

so, I just check if an employee is valid and, if yes, I'll add. If isn't valid I'll show some advices and danger message in my view.
So I would check if users choose or not a department. In other word, I would check if in my employee there is the string "None", so it means user don't choose and option from select. So, in this case, I would set "choose a department". I would have something like this:

[image]

To achieve this aim, so I would use some validation for a class, using something like a System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations compareAttribute. So I'm thinking to write something like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Matricola { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //TODO understand how I can compare this field with a string
    //if I receive string "None", employee is invalid and I have to notificate to user in view
    [Compare("None",ErrorMessage ="choose a department from list")]
    public OptionListDepartments Department { get; set; }
```

OptionListDepartments is just an enum like this:

```
public enum OptionListDepartments
{
    None,
    IT,
    HR,
    Payroll
}
```

How can I achieve my aim?
Thanks in advice for your responses.

Comment: If _None_ is an invalid choice why do you have it in your enum? Otherwise the solution is in this QA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099817/how-to-validate-dropdownlist-using-the-dataannotation

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to resolve my problem!
I just created a variable in my model and assigned a static value in costructor. So the class looks like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    //none variable for compare,only get, you cannot set it
    public string noneDepartment {get;}

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(6,ErrorMessage ="matricola cannot exceed 6 chars")]
    public string Matricola { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //[RegularExpression("some",ErrorMessage ="email non valida")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //if string from form is equal noneDepartment(setted in costructor with "NONE")
    //so we'll show an error message
    [Compare("noneDepartment", ErrorMessage ="Choose a department from list")]
    public OptionListDepartments Department { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        noneDepartment = "None";
    }
```

It works properly and it is like when you, using javascript see an invalid value in a option, like, for instance -1.